# Problem "Go to Page", Footnote in Table

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx, footmisc

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\begin{document}
FIRST PAGE
\newpage

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 1. page}& 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 1. page} \\ \hline
    B & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 1. page} \\ \hline
    C & 3 & 3 & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 2. page}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 2. Page} \\ \hline
    B & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
    C & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 1. Page} \\ \hline
    B & 2\footnote{Go to 2. Page} & 1 \\ \hline
    C & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 1. Page} \\ \hline
    B & 2\footnote{Go to 1. Page} & 1 \\ \hline
    C\footnote{Go to 2. Page} & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And output

[image: compilation result]

As a matter of fact, whole footnotes are written `Go to 2. page` in mouse message. How will I correct my MWE? Maybe `threeparttable`?

Related: [Footnote in table appears on wrong page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182583/footnote-in-table-appears-on-wrong-page)

**[ EDITED ]** for @JohnKormylo's answer

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
FIRST PAGE

\newpage

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|c|c|}
\hline
A & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 1. page}& 1\hyperlink{z}{\ \color{magenta}{$^{2}$}}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{1}\footnotetext{\hypertarget{z}{\blindtext}} & 2\\ \hline
B & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
C & 3 & 3 & 1 & 2\footnote{Go to 2. page}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\newpage

FIRST PAGE

\newpage

FIRST PAGE

\end{document}
```

And, second footnote click output

[image]

and, third footnote click output

[image]

As can be seen, second footnote is starting half. Third footnote is starting exactly line. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Why not use \hyperlink{targetname}{2} for example and link the table entry directly to \hypertarget{targetname}{some text here}?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I did used it. I changed your answer. Please see my question has been edited

Comment: Actually, I thought you wanted to link directly to the page, not the footnotes.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Ok.

Comment: Anyway, it seems hyperref and footnote are out of sync.  Jumping to the first page is the default for an unknown target.  The last links to the first, no matter ow many footnotes are used.  The problem is that hyperref and footnote (mdwtools) use a lot of the same names and may just be plain incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

With the [tablefootnote package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) and additionally `\spewtabnotes` you should be able to get the desired footnotes/links:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\spewtabnotes}{%
\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
\global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax%
\gdef\tfn@fnt{0}}%
\makeatother%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
FIRST PAGE    
\newpage
\phantomsection\label{interesting}SECOND PAGE    

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|c|c|}
\hline
A & 1 & 2\tablefootnote{Go to 1. page}& 1\tablefootnote{\blindtext} & 2\\ \hline
B & 2 & 1& 1 & 2 \\ \hline
C & 3 & 3 & 1 & 2 \tablefootnote{Go to \protect\pageref{interesting}. page}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\spewtabnotes

\newpage THIRD PAGE
\newpage FOURTH PAGE
\end{document}
```

And when you use `hyperref` anyway, you can also link to the targeted page.